# How to understand this expression:"future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url "

Tags: python-3.x, grammar

When I was at the official documentation, [see this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example):

```
urls = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
    'http://www.cnn.com/',
    'http://europe.wsj.com/',
    'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
    'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in urls}  
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

However, I don't understant the meaning of the expression:

"future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url "

is it from which a grammar points? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is a `dict`(dictionary) comprehension expression, just like `list` comprehension expresion. The operator is `{}`, not `[]`. Because we define `dictionary` literal with `{}`. For example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
# key is `'name' + str(x)`, value is `x`
print({ 'name' + str(x): x for x in l })
# {'name2': 2, 'name3': 3, 'name1': 1}
```

The key of the dict in the above code is `'name' + str(x)`, the value is `x`.
So in `{executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in urls}`, the key of generated dict is `executor.submit(load_url, url, 60)`, the value is `url`.

More about dict comprehensions, refer to [Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).